# Using java appender in Log4perl?

Tags: perl

I have a custom java log4j appender class like com.xyz.abc.MyCustomAppender. I am able to use that appender in my log4j.xml file (as below) and works perfectly fine. Now I have to use the same appender in my perl using Log4perl. I have that Log4perl provides lot of appenders that are inbuilt, but I would like to use my own appender along with Log4perl. Can anyone has a sample code for this please provide me.

```
<appender name="Custom_Apppender_1" class="com.xyz.abc.MyCustomAppender">
<param name="...." value="...">
<param name="...." value="...">
<param name="...." value="...">
<param name="...." value="...">
</appender>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use [Log::Log4perl::Appender::String](http://p3rl.org/Log%3a%3aLog4perl%3a%3aAppender%3a%3aString) as an example: it looks very simple.

Also [Log::Log4perl::Appender](http://p3rl.org/Log%3a%3aLog4perl%3a%3aAppender) (base class) documentation may be useful for you.